# Dialog content does not get updated

Tags: html, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have searched this for hours, and I've found some stackoverflow questions related to it, but could not find a solution. I have a primefaces dialog that displays the content of a log file. The dialog is shown when pressing a button. My problem is that once the dialog is displayed, the content is never updated. That is, the `#{pvtRunner.pvtLog}` method is never called. How can I make my dialog call this method every time it is displayed, not just for the first time?

```
<h:head>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <p:dialog id="logDialog" header="PVT Log" widgetVar="dlg" height="400" width="600" dynamic="true">
        <h:outputText id="logDialogContnet" value="#{pvtRunner.pvtLog}" escape="false"/>
    </p:dialog>

    <h:form>
        <p:panelGrid id="mainPanelGrid" columns="1" styleClass="panelGridBorder panelGridCenter">
            ....
            <p:commandButton id="showLog" value="Show Log" onclick="dlg.show()" type="button" update=":logDialogContnet"/>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

This is the java method that should update the dialog content:

```
public String getPvtLog() {
        String result = "";
        try {
            File logFile = new File(instanceRoot + "\\config\\ProcessVerification.log");
            InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(logFile);
            result = readStream(fis);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.severe(e.getMessage());
        }
        return result;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you post the code of the method you are calling `pvtRunner.pvtLog`? Are you sure that the value changes and there is no update or could it be that the value does not change and there is an update?

Comment: I'm debugging - I only hit the breackpoint during the first call.

Comment: that dialog needs to be inside a `<h:form/>` if it's going to be able to send any requests to the server during the request lifecycle. Also move the processing you're doing in `getPvtLog` somewhere else, maybe onclick of the `<p:commandButton/>`. Otherwise, you're setting yourself up for some longterm bugs in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, [stop doing your business logic in your getter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times/2090062#2090062). You should simply be returning the property. Below is one approach you could use. Make sure you check the link.

Modify your `getPvtLog()`

```
public String getPvtLog() {
    return result;
}
```

Then define a method that will be used for your `actionListener` in `<p:commandButton>`to update `result`. Example:

```
public void click() {    
    try {
        File logFile = new File(instanceRoot + "\\config\\ProcessVerification.log");
        InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(logFile);
        result = readStream(fis);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.severe(e.getMessage());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Change the method name as you see fit. This is just a quick example.

Now remove `type="button"` and instead of `onclick` change it to `oncomplete`. `onclick` is executed before an ajax request, you want `<p:dialog>` to pop up after the ajax request. I believe this is your main issue by the way. Also add an `actionListener` in your `<p:commandButton>`.

```
<p:commandButton id="showLog" actionListener="#{pvtRunner.click()}" value="Show Log" oncomplete="dlg.show()" update=":logDialogContnet"/>
```

**Sample**

```
<p:dialog id="logDialog" header="PVT Log" widgetVar="dlg" height="400" width="600" dynamic="true">
    <h:outputText id="logDialogContnet" value="#{pvtRunner.pvtLog}" escape="false"/>
</p:dialog>
<h:form>
    <p:panelGrid id="mainPanelGrid" columns="1" styleClass="panelGridBorder panelGridCenter">
        <p:commandButton id="showLog" actionListener="#{pvtRunner.click()}" value="Show Log" oncomplete="dlg.show()" update=":logDialogContnet"/>
    </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Thanks. It works now. I refactored the get method - it was only temporary

Answer (score 1):

The dialog ought to have it's own `<h:form/>` if it's to be able to successfully call `getPvtLog()`. Per JSF rules, only components wrapped in a form will be able to send traffic to the server. So you should have:

```
<p:dialog id="logDialog" header="PVT Log" widgetVar="dlg" height="400" width="600" dynamic="true">
   <h:form>
    <h:outputText id="logDialogContnet" value="#{pvtRunner.pvtLog}" escape="false"/>
   </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

On an unrelated note, you should move all that logic in your `getPvtLog()` outside of that method.

See why:

- [Perform business logic after getters are called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568838/perform-business-logic-after-getters-are-called)
- [Why JSF calls getters multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times/2090062#2090062)
- [Initialization of List in a JSF Managed bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773350/initialization-of-list-in-a-jsf-managed-bean/15774143#15774143)
- [Request parameter is null during postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14567920/request-parameter-is-null-during-postback/14570012#14570012)

Comment: I tried your answer. It doesn't work. The trouble is with `onclick` because it's executed before an ajax request. It doesn't matter if `<p:dialog>` is inside a `<h:form>` or not. I can update my answer so you can try for yourself if you'd like. Maybe I'm not seeing everything you're doing but all I did was use his code and added the form like you suggested. I even have a silly `PvtRunner` class. Maybe I'm missing something ?

Comment: Even tried mixing your answer with your comment by adding the form processing inside the `onclick` and it still doesn't work. The value never gets updated.

Comment: @Andy - I didn't literally mean the `onclick` event. You can use the `action` attribute of the `<p:commandButton/>` to initialize the data and then use the `oncomplete` event of the button to call `dlg.show()`. I'll update my answer with a snippet

Comment: Oh, it's fine you don't have to. We're doing the (almost) same thing then. But also, you don't need the content of `<p:dialog>` to be in `<h:form>`. It only contains `outputText` and it's not sending data to the server. It will work without it.

Comment: @Andy - `getPvtLog()` will not be called if it's not in a `<h:form/>`

Comment: Then why those the code above work (the **sample**)? By the way it doesn't matter if you do `update=":logDialogContnet"` or `update=":logDialog"`, it still works. Do you want me to post the bean again ? You can try it yourself. I'm not trying to argue by the way kolossus, I'm only trying to understand. If it seems like I am, sorry.

Comment: I'm even looking at the developer's guide for `<p:dialog>`, they are not using `<h:form>`. It doesn't seem like it's a requirement. From what I understand, it depends on what you need to do. In his case he's only displaying a value. He doesn't need it to be wrapped in a form.