# Update a object in a list

Tags: jsf

People, I am with the following problem:

I have an object **A** that has a list of objects **B**.

But the number of objects in the list B is fixed (equal to 12, is an object with the month of the year and a value)

```
public class A{
    private Map<Integer, B> itens;         

    //gets e sets
}

public class B{
    private BigDecimal valor;
    private Date mes;  

    //gets e sets
}
```

I have the following question:

> How can I be able to access this attribute value using JSF?

I've tried the following ways:

```
<h:outputLabel value="#{msg['label.mes.janeiro']}:" />
<h:inputText id="janeiro" styleClass="input-large money"
    value="#{levantamentoBean.itemCrud.itens[0].valor}">
</h:inputText>
```

and

```
 <h:outputLabel value="#{msg['label.mes.janeiro']}:" />
 <h:inputText id="janeiro" styleClass="input-large money"
        value="#{levantamentoBean.itemCrud.itens[0].valor}">
        <f:convertNumber pattern="#,##0.00" minFractionDigits="2" />
 </h:inputText>
```

When I receive the object in my Bean, it does not come with the updated value, that I entered in the input. Someone can tell me if this is possible?

Comment: I  think with the BigDecimal auto-conversion will be the problem. I am to lazzy to test it. Try to set a different type for test proposes

Comment: Why would you use a `List` instead of a `Map`? With a Map you can index by the name of the month.

Comment: Your code is not very clear but it seems like you are returning a class A value, is that necesary? Why don't you return the element instead (class B)?

Comment: Like @danRod said, your question is unclear. Are you interested only in item 0 of the list? At any rate, [you should move that logic in `getValorPorMes`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15568838/1530938) into a `@PostConstruct` method. There are valid reasons why both of the options you've tried are not going to work

Comment: @PauloDiogo hehe, told you :)

Comment: @PauloDiogo as matheszabi stated the problem with the bigDecimal, it could be the lack of a proper converter, dig around the internet, you will find some interesting things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was solved with this:

```
<h:commandLink value="Save" actionListener="#{myBean.saveItem}">                                
    <f:ajax onevent="handleOutcome" execute="@all" 
             render=":formulario:table values descriptionNeed" />
</h:commandLink>
```

I put `execute="@all"` in the `<h:commandLink>`, that sent `All component identifiers` to the server.

References:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkabr.html

[What is <f:ajax execute="@all"> really supposed to do? It POSTs only the enclosing form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999101/jsf-2-0-with-fajax-execute-all)

https://community.jboss.org/message/563111

http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-ajax-hello-world-example/

That is it!

Answer (score 1):

```
<h:inputText id="janeiro" styleClass="input-large money" 
        value="#{levantamentoBean.itemCrud.itens[0].valor}">
    <f:converter converterId="javax.faces.BigDecimal"/>
</h:inputText>
```

If you need the pattern conversion see https://community.jboss.org/message/483357#483357

Comment: man, if I don't update the fields when I submit the form, in a second time the previous value is saved, like: the first value was 1, I changed the value to 1000, the value saved was 1, in a second moment I don't update the fields, the value comes 1000, if I changed the value for 2000, the value saved was 1000.

Comment: Please show us more details of your code. The classes `A` and `B` are a bit too unspecific. ;-) Also please post the relevant parts of the facelet, i.e. the form and its active elements.

Comment: @matheszabi, @Jorge Campos, @danRod, @ChristophT ,peopple i solved the problem with ``execute="@all"`` in my ``<h:commandLink>`` =D thx for your support!